# prevent click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, bpopup

I am using bPopup plugin for jQuery and all is working fine except clicking. When I click on a link it opens a popup. Then when I click on another link it opens again a popup.

So I see that e.preventdefault is not working. How to make this to work to prevent click on other links?

```
// Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
// Encapsulation
// $ is assigned to jQuery
;(function($) {

// DOM Ready
$(function() {

    // Binding a click event
    // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
    $('#PopUpItUp').live('click', function(e) {

    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
    e.preventDefault();

    // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
    $('#popup').bPopup({follow: [false, false], position: [310, 25]});

        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What do you want? One popup at a time? A modal?

Comment: I don't know bPopup, but most Popup-libs I know offer some kind of `modal` option, which prevents any input to the site while the dialog is open. Maybe you can find something like this as well?

Comment: You're saying when you click *any other link* besides the "#PopUpItUp" link, the popup shows up?

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` method doesn't verify if your popup is already opened! It simply prevent the default action of an `a` element.

**Live method is deprecated**

I think you need this:

```
$(function() {

    var opened = false;

    $('#PopUpItUp').click(function(e) {

      // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
      e.preventDefault();

      if(!opened) {
        // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
        $('#popup').bPopup({follow: [false, false], position: [310, 25]});
        opened = true;
      }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I don't know why you choosed to use `.live()` method.. you simply have to use `.click()` method because you can't have more then just one element with `#PopItUp` id

Answer (score 0):

First of you have to understand  e.preventDefault(); It only prevents default action such as hyperlink, form submit action action.

Here is the working example of what you wanted.

http://plnkr.co/edit/v2yx7amBuv2SDCJ0YchB

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all for help. But i see in Fiddle that code works (Jigar Patel) but in my index.php it does not work...so i fired up firebug and see error Reference Error e.PreventDefault(). e is not defined. So on other links that does not have id of PopUpItUp fires bpopup window, here      is code at which     firebug breaks and      display error:

```
function ShowIMDBInfo(id)
{
$.ajax({
url: 'http://myurladdress/external.php?id='+id,
success: function(data) {
$('#popup').html('<div>' + data + '</div>');
},
error: function(request, error, errormessage) {
$("#messages").html(error + '\n' + errormessage);
}
});
e.preventdefault();
return false;
};
```

Comment: it now worked above code like charm..:))) Thanks all for help...the problem was that i was not closing </div> when define id="popup" so whole element which contains href elements get fired when i click, </div> fixed this issue...it was my mistake..